# Python second "if statement" negates first one

Tags: python, if-statement

If I have two if statements followed by an else then the first one is essentially ignored:

```
x = 3
if x == 3:
    test = 'True'
if x == 5:
    test = 'False'
else:
    test = 'Inconclusive'

print(test)
```

Returns:

```
Inconclusive
```

It seems to me that since the first if statement is True then the result should be "True". In order for that to happen the second if statement must be changed to "elif". Does anyone know why?

Comment: The `else` is attached to the preceding `if`...what are you not understanding here?

Comment: Because the second `if..else` is **still executed**. Did you want to use `if..elif..else` instead?

Comment: Thanks Mitch I get it now. I better delete this one as it's getting a lot of down votes :). I just thought that it should look at the first inequality I didn't realize that they're independent.

Comment: `test` _is_ set to 'True' and then it's set to 'Inconclusive'.  You can see that if you throw in another print call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two **independent** `if` statements. That the second such statement has an `else` suite doesn't matter here; that `else` suite is picked on the basis of the condition attached to the second `if` test; whatever happened in the first `if` statement **doesn't matter**.

If you want the two `x` tests to *not* be independent, use *one* `if` statement and use an `elif` suite for the second test:

```
if x == 3:
    test = 'True'
elif x == 5:
    test = 'False'
else:
    test = 'Inconclusive'
```

The `elif` here is part of the single `if` statement, and now only one of the three blocks is executed.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `if-elif-else` statement instead. Currently, your code is performing

```
x = 3
if x == 3: # This will be True, so test = "True"
    test = 'True'
if x == 5: # This will be also tested because it is a new if statement. It will return False, so it will enter else statement where sets test = "Inconclusive"
    test = 'False'
else:
    test = 'Inconclusive'
```

Instead use:

```
x = 3
if x == 3: # Will be true, so test = "True"
    test = 'True'
elif x == 5: # As first if was already True, this won't run, neither will else statement
    test = 'False'
else:
    test = 'Inconclusive'

print(test)
```